# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'plot' in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I tried to visualize the nulls values in each column but got the error: `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'plot'.`

```
columns_with_null = ['ACCTAGE', 'PHONE', 'POS','INV','INVBAL','POSAMT', 'CC', 'CCBAL','HMOWN'
                    'CCPURC', 'INCOME', 'LORES', 'HMVAL', 'AGE','CRSCORE']

for col in columns_with_null:

    print('COLUMN:', col)
    print('percent of nulls:', df[col].isna().sum()/len(df))

    # Viz the value counts
    df[col].isna().sum()/len(df).plot(kind='barh')
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Could you please add the code where you're creating / modifying `plt`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need pass all columns with nulls instead `col` variable and also add parentheses or `div` for division:

```
(df[columns_with_null].isna().sum() / len(df)).plot(kind='barh')

df[columns_with_null].isna().sum().div(len(df)).plot(kind='barh')
```

If want plot all columns:

```
(df.isna().sum() / len(df)).plot(kind='barh')

df.isna().sum().div(len(df)).plot(kind='barh')
```

---

Problem of your solution is part:

```
len(df).plot(kind='barh')
```

because `len(df)` return length of DataFrame, here integers and you want plot it. Another problem is first part also return integer, because processing only one column - `df[col].isna().sum()`.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `sum()` returns a single value which is the sum of all the values of `df[col]`. Now everything onwards is just processing that single number.

- If you want to plot the whole dataframe, then `df[col].plot()` might help
- If you want to work with avg value of the dataframe then simplest would be to print it
- If you still want to plot that single value, you have to use external libraries like `matplotlib`